# htaccess redirect error when user is googlebot

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, googlebot, hashbang

I have a web site created with `angularjs`. i want to redirect to a `PHP` page when user is a `GoogleBot` and for this i add some rules to `htaccess` file.

but when i test from google bot this role does not execute.

my `htaccess` is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-site.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.my-site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(panel|lists)($|/) - [L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  (googlebot|InfoSeek|msnbot|Surp) [NC]
RewriteRule ^estate/([0-9]+)/?$ http://www.my-site.com/static-estate.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !ajax
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#!/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


RedirectMatch 301 /%{REQUEST_FILENAME}/(.*) #!/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}/$1
```

i expect that this url

```
http://www.my-site.com/estate/123/text
```

redirect to :

```
http://www.my-site.com/static-estate.php?id=123
```

when user is `GoogleBot`. but it redirects to

```
http://www.my-site.com/#!/estate/123/text
```

and by following url redirects to

```
http://www.my-site.com/
```

what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
RewriteRule ^estate/([0-9]+)/?$ http://www.my-site.com/static-estate.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

because `^estate/([0-9]+)/?$` will not accept anything after `/estate/123/`

The exact correct line depends on if `/text` is mandatory or optional, but something like this should do:

```
RewriteRule ^estate/([0-9]+)(/?|/[a-zA-Z0-9]*)/?$ http://www.example.com/static-estate.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```